# MikTeX Czech typeset

Tags: fonts, errors, miktex, font-encodings

I use MikTeX and I need to get the Czech typeset (setting Czech characters), web advised me to use this:

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
```

First two rows work, but with the third one error occurs:

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file 'il2enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                  You might have misspelt the name of encoding.
See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
```

Third command was advised on more websites so I do not think that I misspelled it.
I'd know whether it is necessary to download some extra package.

Comment: il2enc.def is in the cslatex package. You can install it with the package manager. (But probably it would be better to use xelatex instead).

Answer (score 3):

il2enc.def is in the cslatex package. You can install it with the package manager. (But probably it would be better to use xelatex instead).